# Pronunciation in “духи” (perfume) and (spirits)

Tags: произношение

I went on wikipedia and i understood the stressed but i dont understand the sound of х in these words thank you

Comment: Have you tried to check an article on `x` letter? Have you tried to check how it sounds in google translate?

Comment: @shabunc yes but slepovs answer helped because i am using a voice recognition program and after slepovs help it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sound of **х** is close to that of **ch** in Loch Ness. A more intense **h** as in Tahini.